# Passing multiple reducers to store(ngrx/store) in angular 2 with typescript?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to pass multiple reducer functions to store in angular 2. I tried it, but I don't know whether it is right way or not? Like:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ StoreModule.provideStore({todo: appStore, selectedTodo: todoSelector}, {todo: [], selectedTodo: {}}) ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers: [ ...],
    bootstrap: [ ...]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

here, **appStore** - which returns todolist and **todoSelector** - which returns selected todo details are **reducers** like:

```
export const appStore: ActionReducer<Todo[]> = (state: Todo[] = [], action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_LIST: return action.payload;
        default: return state;
    }
}

export const todoSelector: ActionReducer<Todo> = (state: Todo, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {  
        case GET_DETAILS: return action.payload;
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

In root component, I used store like this:

```
export class AppComponent{
    private seletedTodo:Todo;
    private $todoList: Observable<number>;

    constructor(private _todoService: TodoService, private _store: Store<number>){
        ...
        this.$todoList = this._store.select('todo');
        this._store.select('selectedTodo').subscribe(todo => this.seletedTodo = todo );
    }

    onSelection(data: Todo){
        this._store.dispatch({type: 'GET_DETAILS', payload: data});
    }
}
```

Is it right way to do it or not?

Answer (score 4):

I believe when you bootstrap your app using `StoreModule.provideStore()`, you need to reference the names of the reducers exactly:

```
imports: [ StoreModule.provideStore({appStore, todoSelector} ],
```

when this is processed, the reducers are all pulled together, so they are accessible to the ngrx store.  The `state` associated with the `GET_LIST` action will be affected when `GET_LIST` is invoked, and the state associated with the `GET_DETAILS` action will be affected when `GET_DETAILS` is invoked.  In each reducer definition, you set state to an empty array, so the state for each will reference their respective arrays.  Both arrays are available on the store itself.  The name of the reducer is how you reference that particular slice of `state`, so you could do something like the following (I've simplified it a little for the sake of the example, but removing the parts I did aren't necessarily my suggested action):

```
export class AppComponent {
    private _todoList;
    private _appStore;

    constructor( private _store: Store<any> ) {
        this._todoList = this._store.select('todoSelector');
        this._appStore = this._store.select('appStore');
    }

    onSelection(data: Todo){
        this._store.dispatch({type: 'GET_DETAILS', payload: data});
    }
}
```

In your template, you can now reference the data in this._todoList and this._appStore using the `async` pipe.

```
[todoList]="_todoList | async"
[appStore]="_appStore | async"
```

and the child component that receives `todoList` and `appStore` will have a live updating feed of data from each.  If they change, it will propagate down to the child components they're used in.  To allow passing them to a child component, use the `@Input` decorator in the child component definition.

If you want the `appStore` reducer to reference a single Todo, change the reducer name to better suit it's use.

If you have questions beyond that, post them and I'll ammend my answer as best I can.

Comment: thanks, nice explanation, here I have created two reducers to update two different views, one view shows list of todos and other view shows the todo details when user clicks on any item in todo list. is it right way to do that? is there really need to create two separate reducrers to achieve it?